# How to handle same touch events in iOS from different objects of the same class?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, events

I have a class TouchImageView that is a subclass of UIImageView. I want objects of this class to handle touch events. It inherits all UIImageView's properties and methods and I enable user interaction, override [init] and [touchesBegan:WithEvent]. And the objects of this class are being created in code and added as subviews to the main view. What I need now is to handle touch events fired by these "TouchImageViews". I know how to create control in Interface Builder and then link just it's particular event with the IBAction of the controller. But I can't find the way to deal with programatically created views. There is nothing to drag and drop with the mouse, because the TouchImageView object is created later during the runtime.

The question is: how does the handler [touchesBegan:WithEvent] know which of the "views" fired the event?

If it's not possible to describe this in two words could you please suggest reading on this topic or Apple's code samples which include required procedures?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gesture recognizers is a good way to go.  These are objects that you can attach to any view (i.e. any object whose class inherits from UIView).  You attach a gesture recognizer for each type of touch gesture you want to respond to, and then write a selector method to handle it any way you like.

Apple's [Event Handling Guide for iOS, chapter 3](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1), gives a pretty good explanation, along with the code to create the gesture recognizers, as well as the code for the selector methods to handle touch events.  Once you become a bit familiar with them, they're fairly easy to use and require fairly little code.

Comment: Thanks. Gesture Recognizers approach is propably the best solution in this situation. In case someone else will search this I created UITapGestureRecognizer (allocate and initialized with appropriate action signature). Then I added this new Gesture Recognizer to the view i wanted to fire events (the view has addGestureRecognizer method). I found some examples here [link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html)